# Can't update @INC with export PERL5LIB

Tags: perl

I'm trying to add the HTML::Entities module path to `@INC`. I did export `PERL5LIB=/mypath/HTML/` followed by `source ~/.bashrc`. That path is reflected in `PERL5LIB`, but not in `@INC`. Is there an additional step that I'm missing?

I'm using perl 5.26.2 on CentOS6.5

Edit:

I (wrongly) assumed that my path wasn't being added to @INC because when I run my perl script I get

```
Can't locate HTML/Entities.pm in @INC (you may need to install the HTML::Entities module)
(@INC contains:
/home/hek/anaconda3/bin/aux/lib/perl5
/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2
/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2
)
```

(Line breaks added for readability)

But it does appear below

```
echo $PERL5LIB
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root//usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl:/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib/perl5:/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root//usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl:/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/HTML/

perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\@INC), "\n"'
$VAR1 = [
          '/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root//usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl',
          '/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib/perl5',
          '/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root//usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl',
          '/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/HTML/',
          '/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi',
          '/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2',
          '/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi',
          '/home/hek/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2',
          '.'
        ];
```

Why would there be this discrepency?

I do have multiple versions of perl installed, but `which perl` returns the version that I need to use, `~/anaconda3/bin/perl`.

I tried changing the shebang in my script from `#!/usr/bin/env perl` to `#!/~/anaconda3/bin/perl`, but that didn't help.

Comment: How exactly have you tested what was in PERL5LIB and what was in @INC?

Comment: Yes, please test by data dumping @INC like so:

`perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\@INC), "\n"'`

Comment: You need to show your script and how you're running it. In short, post a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't read the Q carefully -- yes, you run v5.26.2 and use module installed for v5.14.2 what isn't right (as my now deleted comment said), but that wouldn't cause the error you report. On the other hand, your actual run indeed doesn't get that `PERL5LIB` as you susspected

Comment: It seems that altogether you only need to install `HTML::Entities` under the perl you want to use, v5.26.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Either the `PERL5LIB` env var wasn't set in the parent of the `perl` process giving the error (e.g. you launched it from a web server), or
- The `-T` command line switch was provided to `perl` process giving the error (since this causes `PERL5LIB` to be ignored).

In either case, you can use `use lib` in the source instead of `PERL5LIB`.

Answer (score 1):

`use HTML::Entities` looks for a file `HTML/Entities.pm` in the directories in `@INC`. No such path is found because it's looking for ones like `/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/HTML/HTML/Entities.pm`.

Leave off the `HTML/` part in the directory you're trying to add to the search path and you might have better luck.

Edit: There's still the version mismatch, but as long as the module is pure Perl without any XS components I don't *think* that will be a big problem. Still better to get it in the right path for the version of perl you're actually using. Do that and you shouldn't have to manipulate the search path at all.

Comment: This doesn't help at all. `/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/HTML` is not in the error message, so the problem is not that `/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/HTML` instead of `/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`. In fact, what you are suggesting is harmful. You should not provided a path that contains modules installed using 5.14 to a 5.26 build of Perl!!!!

Comment: This won't cause the reported error as @ikegami says, but it does raise other valid problems -- while it needs to solve them both (not use a wrong-version path while solving the first problem). I'd suggest to edit so to include a correct-version path, and perhaps add a comment to state that these are yet other errors? (So the readers don't neglect it once they see that it doesn't solve the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

This is to summarize the problems and state what seems to be the simplest solution.

From the output of your test one-liner it is clear that a module installed under v5.14.2 is used in a program meant to run under v5.26.2. That is not good, even if it happens to work.

So install `HTML::Entities` under the perl build that needs it, v5.26.2.

That also solves the problem you are asking about, since then you won't have to muck about with `PERL5LIB` or anything else.

Further, the `@INC` in your one-liner test clearly *isn't* loaded in your real run, just as you suspected. Possible reasons are given in ikegami's answer, as well as the solution, to `use lib "...";`.  But then you need to use the module version installed for v5.26.2, and once you installed it with that perl there'll actually be no need to specify extra library paths.

Finally, if you end up needing to add that path for some reason, leave off the `HTML` (last) directory, as Shawn's answer indicates. With `use HTML::Entities` the directory `HTML` will be searched (for `Entities.pm` file) and you only need to provide the directory that contains it.